# What is a "terminated object", and why can't I call methods on it?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

Periodically I get this exception:

```
NotImplementedError: method `at' called on terminated object
```

on this line of code:

```
next if Hpricot(html).at('a')
```

What does this error mean? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Does it also happen if you assign the result of `Hpricot(html)` to a variable before whole loop instead of performing it every time?

Comment: `html` is the loop parameter, so I can't do it *before* the loop, though I could do something like `doc = Hpricot(html)` at the top of the loop and do `doc.at('a')`. I'll give this a try

Answer (score 2):

The library you are using makes use of a custom C extension. In the C extension, it is trying to call a method on a Ruby object which has already been garbage-collected.

This can't happen in pure Ruby, because the garbage collector will only free objects which are no longer accessible from any reference. But in C, it is possible to have a reference remaining to a Ruby object, in a place which the garbage collector doesn't check (for example, the compiler may have put a variable in a CPU register).

Answer (score 0):

It might be a linking problem. Check that you didn't link the extension twice.

Comment: By "link the extension twice", do you mean "`require` the extension twice"? (Isn't `require` designed to make sure this doesn't cause problems?)